# How to use while loop inside a function?

Tags: while-loop, python-2.x, raw-input

I decide to modify the following while loop and use it inside a function so that the loop can take any value instead of 6.

```py
i = 0
numbers = []
while i < 6:
    numbers.append(i)
    i += 1
```

I created the following script so that I can use the variable(or more specifically argument ) instead of 6 .

```py
def numbers(limit):
    i = 0
    numbers = []
    
    while i < limit:
        numbers.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    print numbers
```

```
user_limit = raw_input("Give me a limit ")      
numbers(user_limit)
```

When I didn't use the `raw_input()` and simply put the arguments from the script it was working fine but now when I run it(in Microsoft Powershell) a cursor blinks continuously after the question in `raw_input()` is asked. Then i have to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to abort it. Maybe the function is not getting called after `raw_input()`.

Now it is giving a memory error like in the pic.
[image]

Comment: did you press `enter` after the input?

Comment: If you upgraded to Python 3.x then you would have had an error You should consider whether you really need to run such an ancient version of Python.

Comment: You are doing an infinite loop, see answer belows. Your i<limit test always returns True because limit is a string

Comment: @Duncan I am following a book and now it works

Comment: Of course, your `numbers` function duplicates the built-in `range` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert `user_limit` to `Int`:

`raw_input()` return value is `str` and the statement is using i which is `int`

```
def numbers(limit):
    i = 0
    numbers = []

    while i < limit:
        numbers.append(i)
        i = i + 1
    print numbers

user_limit = int(raw_input("Give me a limit "))
numbers(user_limit)
```

Output:

```
Give me a limit 8
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Cf CPython manual : CPython implementation detail: Objects of different types except numbers are ordered by their type names; objects of the same types that don’t support proper comparison are ordered by their address. integer are always "lesser than" string. Test : 1<'1'

Comment: @Raphaël Braud yes you are right, that's why it's an endless loop.

Comment: and that's why it gave me a memory error. Thanks! now it's working fine!